# How can i limit the input with javascript or html to letters only, but allow a space to be entered as well?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I need to limit the input allowed in this input element. I've tried using this code, however, this code does not allow someone to enter a space.

```
<input type="text" id="wisselspelers" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
    event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)">
```

Only letters should be allowed. Any number or other input (e.g. <;<.>'" etc.) should not be allowed.

In regards to a user being able to only enter a space, i've created this JS code which forces a user to, at the very least, enter something:

```
 var input = document.getElementById("wisselspelers").value;
            if (input.trim().length == 0) {

                alert("Een naam is verplicht om op te kunnen slaan!");
                return;
            }
            if (input.trim().length == 1) {
                alert("Een naam kan niet maar 1 letter hebben, vul een naam in!");
                return;
            }
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("wisselspelers").value;
if (input.trim().length == 0) {

  alert("A name is required to save! (en naam is verplicht om op te kunnen slaan!)");

}
if (input.trim().length == 1) {
  alert("A name cannot have only 1 letter, enter a name! (Een naam kan niet maar 1 letter hebben, vul een naam in!)");

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="wisselspelers" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
    event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII for space is [**32**](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/space-ascii-code-32.html)

Thus, you can use

```
event.charCode == 32
```

for the spaces to be accepted.

For making user force to **at least** add more than 1 characters you can use [`focusout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) event

```js
document.getElementById("wisselspelers")
  .addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
    var input = document.getElementById("wisselspelers").value;
    if (input.trim().length == 0) {
      alert("A name is required to save! (en naam is verplicht om op te kunnen slaan!)");
    }
    if (input.trim().length == 1) {
      alert("A name cannot have only 1 letter, enter a name! (Een naam kan niet maar 1 letter hebben, vul een naam in!)");
    }
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="wisselspelers" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 32|| event.charCode > 64 && 
        event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)">
```